# Android decode file returns null

Tags: android, file

I have the following code:

```
 Bitmap b= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
```

where the imagPath value is /external/images/media/43426 (I read it by allowing the user to select the image from the phone using this code:

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
imagePath = selectedImage.toString();
```

The problem is that b is always null ! I have added the permission for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, and tried many solutions found on the net but no success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where the imagPath value is /external/images/media/43426

That is not [how to use a `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html), particularly one with a `content` scheme, as yours has.

Either:

- Use one of the many [image loading libraries available for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), passing them the full `Uri`, or
- Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`, then pass that `InputStream` to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`

Answer (score 1):

[From documentation:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String))

> Decode a file path into a bitmap. If the specified file name is null, or cannot be decoded into a bitmap, the function returns null.

By using Logcat, or any logging source, you can verify that `imagePath = "/external/images/media/43426"` is not actually a `File`, just an `URI`

You can get the File or its contents from the URI:

```
Log.v(TAG, "Uri: " + data.getData().toString());
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
```